Getting descriptor value as undefined when using Accessor Decorators
class Point {
  private _x: number;
  constructor(x: number, y: number) {
    this._x = x;
  }
 
  @configurable(false)
  get x() {
    return this._x;
  } 
}

function configurable(value: boolean) {
  return function (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor?: PropertyDescriptor) {
    console.log("called.....", descriptor);
    if (descriptor) {
      console.log("called.....", descriptor);
      descriptor.configurable = value;
    }
  };
}

I have tsconfig file as below
{
"compilerOptions": {
"target": "ES5",
"experimentalDecorators": true,
}
}
As per documentation of typscript I have target as ES5 and using experimentalDecorators to true but still getting descriptor as undefined
I tried lot of solutions but nothing helped

Your code seems to be working fine and descriptor is not undefined as show in this playground. What exactly does not work for you?

I tried to compile with tsc and using .js file in html file, then getting as undefined

I'll have to vote for closing this question then because the error is not reproducible. Please edit and include all relevant details.
